# HTML5 video won't restart on Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm having an issue on Mobile Safari where my HTML5 video won't return to the start once it has finished, so that when it is played again it tries to play the last second before closing once again.

I've attached a handler to the "ended" event so that it closes to the full screen once the video has finished:

```
$(videoID).bind("ended", function() {
      $(videoID).get(0).webkitExitFullScreen(); 
});
```

Any ideas?

I should add that I've tried resetting the currentTime to 0, but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up that I had stupidly put currentTime=0 after exiting full screen when it needed to be before. i.e.

```
$(videoID).bind("ended", function() {
      $(videoID).get(0).currentTime = 0;
      $(videoID).get(0).webkitExitFullScreen();
});
```